# Google reCAPTCHA doesn't work

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, recaptcha

This question has been asked before at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29578250/recaptcha-uncaught-securityerror-blocked-a-frame-with-origin-https-www-googl) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37458183/uncaught-securityerror-blocked-a-frame-with-origin-https-www-google-com-fro). but the solution does not work for me, the reCAPTCHA sometimes works but most of the times doesn't work on my `localhost`! so I tried to switch to **valid** `https` in my development URL on my server, but the problem persists to exist:

> Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "https://www.google.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.   `recaptcha__fa.js:formatted:10721`
>       at Kp.f.Yb (https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/api2/r20170411114922/recaptcha__fa.js:413:353)
>       at Kp.xb (https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/api2/r20170411114922/recaptcha__fa.js:409:59)

I have looked at `line:10721` in `recaptcha__fa.js:formatted` it seems that the error come from `var a = Dg().parent.frames[this.Yc];` which it means the code tries to access the parent's frames.

#### Questions:

1. What is wrong with reCAPTCHA?
2. How can I fix this?

---

#### P.S:

More info:

- Site's framework: Rails
- I use tubrolink.
- This is how I use it (as documents):

```js
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?hl=<%= I18n.locale.to_s %>"></script>
```

```html
<div class='g-recaptcha' data-sitekey='<%= ENV["KEY"] %>' data-callback='alert("IT IS OK")'></div>
```

---

## EDIT

It just took me a day to figure out that it's the `bootstrap modal` that causes the issue... I place the code outside of the modal, everything works fine, but when it's inside the modal it's not!

Has anybody have a workaround for this?

Comment: maybe your web server config prevent cross origin? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44288460/google-recaptcha-uncaught-domexception-blocked-a-frame-with-origin-https-www/46069356#46069356